# Magento 2.4.6 GraphicsMagick Image support error

Tags: image, magento2.4.6, php8.2

I have a magento 2.4.6-p3 instance with php8.2

I have installed [superdav42 / magento-image-quality](https://github.com/superdav42/magento-image-quality) for support of GraphicsMagick Image processing.

I am having this is issue when trying to print PDF from orders:

```
Deprecated Functionality: Gmagick::setcompressionquality(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($quality) of type int is deprecated in /app/code/DevStone/ImageQuality/Image/Adapter/GraphicsMagick.php on line 152
```

This line:

```
$this->_imageHandler->setCompressionQuality($this->quality());
```

And the whole function is:

```
     /**
     * Apply options to image. Will be usable later when create an option container
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _applyOptions()
    {
        $this->_imageHandler->setCompressionQuality($this->quality());
        $this->_imageHandler->setImageCompression(\Gmagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $this->_imageHandler->setImageUnits(\Gmagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
        $this->_imageHandler->setImageResolution(
            $this->_options['resolution']['x'],
            $this->_options['resolution']['y']
        );

        $this->_imageHandler->setinterlacescheme(\Gmagick::INTERLACE_LINE);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AbstractAdapter::getImage
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        $this->_applyOptions();
        return $this->_imageHandler->getImageBlob();
    }
```

Any help please? I am not sure how to fix

Comment: i am already install this module but don't facing any issue when i am print order frontend side and backend side.

Comment: After the module install you can apply deploy commands. 
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/